# Html file explorer for Raspberry

Tags: apache-httpd

I need ur help
I have a apache2 server running on a raspberry pi 3 b+, and i want to explore de files of the folder that apache is pointed to (/var/www), I have searched on the internet and i find a few of them ( http://www.dreamcss.com/2009/05/10-free-and-powerful-file-managers-for.html ) but no one of them worked.
If someone could help me i would be appreciated.
(sorry about my bad English its not my native language)

Comment: Welcome. You mention that the ones you tried didn't work — was there anything in the PHP logs that might help point in the right direction? Any particular errors when trying to use them?

Comment: you want to edit the files? then please read https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/text-editors.md

Comment: You want to see what files are inside a directory? You might want to learn the `ls` command https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/commands.md (for more fun with the command line: https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/issues/essentials-bash-vol1/ you can download it for free)

Answer (score 0):

I checked the PHP logs and serached on the Internet and I found my error, the php7.0 package wasn't completely installed, there was many complements missing I installed then and it worked!
Thanks guys